# Can't seem to be able to redirect without using internal instance of react

Tags: react-router

I had to use this to move to a new page: 
`this._reactInternalInstance._context.history.push('/page-one');`

`this.context` was `{}`
`this.props` was `{}`

Anyone have a hint to fix what I am obviously doing wrong here?
Thanks

`package.json` relevant parts

```
"history": "^1.17.0",
"lodash": "^3.10.1",
"react": "^0.14.3",
"react-addons-css-transition-group": "^0.14.3",
"react-datagrid": "^2.0.1",
"react-dom": "^0.14.3",
"react-multi-dropdown": "^1.0.1",
"react-router": "^1.0.3",
"react-select": "^0.9.1",
"reflux": "^0.3.0",



import React from 'react';
import Reflux from 'reflux';
import RouterContext from 'react-router';
import History from 'history';

import Auth from '../stores/auth-store';

module.exports = React.createClass({
    mixins: [
        Reflux.listenTo(Auth, 'onDataChange'),
        History
    ],
    loginClicked(event) {
        if (Auth.loggedIn()) {
            this._reactInternalInstance._context.history.push('/page-one');
        }
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `contextTypes` to be able to use `this.context`. See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html.